# Print "HELLO" in big block letters?

Tags: c++

How to print "HELLO" in big block letters where each letter is 7 characters high and 5 characters wide?

I thought of printing like this:

```
H   H    EEEEE   L       L        OOOOO
H   H    E       L       L       O     O
H   H    E       L       L       O     O
HHHHH    EEEEE   L       L       O     O
H   H    E       L       L       O     O
H   H    E       L       L       O     O
H   H    EEEEE   LLLLL   LLLLL    OOOOO
```

But I don't know how to print one character beside the other. I have tried to print H and E, but they are not horizontal. They came vertical.

Here is my code:

```
int problem4_4()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<7;++i)
    {
        if(i==3)
            cout<<"HHHHH\n";
        else
            cout<<"H   H\n";
    }

    for(i=7;i<14;i++)
    {
        if(i==7||i==10||i==13)
            cout<<"EEEEE\n";
        else
            cout<<"E\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that you need to print line by line, so you need to print the entire first row, then the entire 2nd row, etc. Try combining those for loops into a single loop

Comment: For a more interesting challenge, make a function which takes an arbitrary string and prints it in big letters.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i assumed thats is the actual exercise - maybe not. Its a nice coffee break puzzle - or code golf

Comment: @pm100: nevermind, misunderstood.

Comment: the interesting one would be to inspect the glyph if each character from an existing font table - rather then just have a big table of precomputed letters. You could use different fonts.

Answer (score 4):

Here is example of the method @Kevin suggested

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

v.push_back("H   H    EEEEE   L       L        OOOOO");
v.push_back("H   H    E       L       L       O     O");
v.push_back("H   H    E       L       L       O     O");
v.push_back("HHHHH    EEEEE   L       L       O     O");
v.push_back("H   H    E       L       L       O     O");
v.push_back("H   H    E       L       L       O     O");
v.push_back("H   H    EEEEE   LLLLL   LLLLL    OOOOO");

for (auto row : v)
{
    for (auto col : row)
        cout << col;
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

Edit:
Per suggestions in comment section, you can draw the letters individually, then add the letters from left to right, put everything in `result` and print

```
void add(std::vector<std::string> &result, const std::vector<std::string> &letter)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < letter.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i >= result.size())
            result.push_back("");
        result[i] += letter[i];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::string> H, E, L, O;

    H.push_back("H   H ");
    H.push_back("H   H ");
    H.push_back("H   H ");
    H.push_back("HHHHH ");
    H.push_back("H   H ");
    H.push_back("H   H ");
    H.push_back("H   H ");

    E.push_back("EEEEE ");
    E.push_back("E     ");
    E.push_back("E     ");
    E.push_back("EEEEE ");
    E.push_back("E     ");
    E.push_back("E     ");
    E.push_back("EEEEE ");

    L.push_back("L     ");
    L.push_back("L     ");
    L.push_back("L     ");
    L.push_back("L     ");
    L.push_back("L     ");
    L.push_back("L     ");
    L.push_back("LLLLL ");

    O.push_back(" OOOOO  ");
    O.push_back("O     O ");
    O.push_back("O     O ");
    O.push_back("O     O ");
    O.push_back("O     O ");
    O.push_back("O     O ");
    O.push_back(" OOOOO  ");

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    add(result, H);
    add(result, E);
    add(result, L);
    add(result, L);
    add(result, O);

    for (unsigned row = 0; row < result.size(); row++)
        std::cout << result[row].c_str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost feels like cheating.

Comment: Very simple solution and I love how you can visually see the giant HELLO in code :). But sindhu didn't specify what version of C++ is being used so wouldn't this work in only C++11?

Comment: If you have to go down this route you can just as well replace each `push_back` with a `cout`. No need for a vector of strings, just `cout` them, hard coded. But I wouldn't follow this approach, because it isn't flexible at all. If you want to write "HOLE" instead of "HELLO" you have to spend some time changing the code, although the letters are the same. I'd go for Dúthomhas's solution.

Comment: Great, this is what I meant. It certainly took more time to write, but this is a much more flexible solution, and it doesn't feel like cheating. +1.

Answer (score 3):

For a hint: each letter is the same size, so make yourself an array of "letters": each is a 2D array of characters that form your letter.

Now, when you go to print, say, "Hello", you can print the first line of each letter, then a newline, then the second line of each letter, then another newline, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a version that is slightly complicated for an example for a beginner, but not too complicated.  It will print arbitrary strings (call it with a command-line argument) and can trivially be extended to new glyphs and even new encodings.  It stores the glyph information in an `unordered_map`, *i.e.* a hash table:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using std::cout;

using ctype = char;
static constexpr unsigned rows = 7;
using letter_t = std::array< std::string, rows >;
using glyph_table = std::unordered_map< ctype, letter_t >;

const glyph_table& create_glyphs()
{
  // Returns a reference to a singleton.
  static glyph_table glyphs;
  static bool ran = false;

  if (!ran) { // Skip this step if called again.
    glyphs.emplace( 'H', letter_t({
      "H   H",
      "H   H",
      "H   H",
      "HHHHH",
      "H   H",
      "H   H",
      "H   H" })
    );
    glyphs.emplace( 'E', letter_t({
      "EEEEE",
      "E    ",
      "E    ",
      "EEEEE",
      "E    ",
      "E    ",
      "EEEEE" })
    );
    glyphs.emplace( 'L', letter_t({
      "L    ",
      "L    ",
      "L    ",
      "L    ",
      "L    ",
      "L    ",
      "LLLLL" })
    );
    glyphs.emplace( 'O', letter_t({
      " OOO ",
      "O   O",
      "O   O",
      "O   O",
      "O   O",
      "O   O",
      " OOO "})
    );
    glyphs.emplace( 0, letter_t({
      "?  ??",
      "??? ?",
      "??? ?",
      "?? ??",
      "?? ??",
      "?????",
      "?? ??" })
    );

    ran = true;
  } // end if

  return glyphs;
}

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )
{
  const char* const message = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "HELLO";
  const glyph_table& glyphs = create_glyphs();

  for ( unsigned i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
    for ( unsigned j = 0; j < 22 && message[j]; ++j ) {
      // Look up the glyph for the jth character of message, or if that isn't in the table, the glyph stored under the null character.
      const letter_t& g = glyphs.count(message[j]) ? glyphs.find(message[j])->second : glyphs.find(0)->second;
      /* The syntax to get a reference to the value indexed by a key from an iterator returned by find() is a little baroque for a STL hash table.
       */
      // Print its ith row:
      cout << ' ' << g[i];
    }
    cout << '\n';
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It would be more efficient in terms of execution time (but not memory) to loop over the characters of the message first, and generate all the rows before printing them.  You can see Barmak Shemirani’s solution for a hint how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Print the contents of a 2-D array.**
Using global variable with a function that can be called from main function:

[image]

```
 /*    THIS PROGRAM IS WRITTEN IN C     */

    /*    HEADER FILES     */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    
    /*   GLOBAL VARIABLES   */
    const char *helloDetail[7][50] =
    {
        {"H   H EEEEE L     L     OOOOO\n"},
        {"H   H E     L     L     O   O\n"},
        {"H   H E     L     L     O   O\n"},
        {"HHHHH EEEEE L     L     O   O\n"},
        {"H   H E     L     L     O   O\n"},
        {"H   H E     L     L     O   O\n"},
        {"H   H EEEEE LLLLL LLLLL OOOOO\n"}
    };
    
    
    /*   Function prototypes   */
    int printDetail();
    
    
    /*   Main Function   */
    int main()
    {
        printDetail();
        
        return 0;
    }
        
    
    /*   Function   */
    int printDetail()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 29; j++)
            {
                printf(helloDetail[i][j]);  
            }       
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```